# Pack stuff into a SQL Server binary data type

Tags: sql-server

What can I do wtih a binary data type in SQL Server to make my life easier?

I recently found out about this nifty feature

```
DECLARE @p0 varbinary(128)
SET @p0 = --?
SET CONTEXT_INFO @p0
```

How can I in a reasonable efficient manner store data that makes some sense in this binary slot? Oh, and then access that data in some reasonable way?

```
SELECT ? = context_info
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE session_id = @@SPID
```

**Update: as pointed out by gbn**

```
SELECT ? = CONTEXT_INFO()
```

A more useful approach would be to rely on CONTEXT_INFO() to return a Row ID of some context table. Say:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ContextTable 
WHERE RowID = CONTEXT_INFO()
```

That would allow me to query context information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useful for passing data into a trigger, say, the username from your web site into a audit trigger.

I'd also use [CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx)() to read the data back out (for SQL Server 2005 and higher)

One gotcha: it starts NULL but you can not assign NULL back to it after use. You have to use 0x00.

Comment: Yes, that's what I aim to do, but the binary isn't really a useful type to work with, now is it?

You could use the @@SPID to maintain a table with state, (that row you can query and that's practical).

Btw, do you know if the CONTEXT_INFO() starts out NULL for each session, becuase that would make sense?

Thanks for the CONTEXT_INFO(), didn't know about that one either. This is great stuff.

Comment: yes, starts at NULL but can't be reset back. I use it for triggers only.